# Problem with emacs and sagemath unicode

Tags: unicode

I am using Emacs (GNU Emacs 24.5.1, which is admittedly old, but the problem also exists on a newer (25 something) Emacs on a different machine) and sage-shell-mode to work with the computer algebra system SageMath.

Unfortunately, Unicode output is garbled.

Here is a picture of how output looks:
[image]

and here is a picture of how it should look:
[image]

I do not know what other information might be useful.
`buffer-file-coding-system` is `utf-8-unix`

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the problem is simply the font.  The font "Noto Mono Regular" is beautiful, but is not monospace, whereas "monospace regular" seems to work correctly.